# How to store a user input char character into a variable/array?

Tags: char, scanf

I'm making a unit converter calculator (ignore the function names they are reversed for a couple of them) and I'm trying to store a user input `char` character (ie. m, g, or c) to represent the unit they want to be converted. My code gets stuck at the `scanf()` function, and not sure why it won't take a single `char` character when I specify the `userUnit` `array` length to 2 (one to hold the null terminator). Any thoughts?

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Function prototypes
double fahrToCelc(double cel);
double meterToFoot(double foot);
double poundToGram(double pound);

int main(){
    double conversions;
    char userUnit[2];
    char letter[4] = "gmc";

    //User inputs
    scanf("%lf %s",&conversions, userUnit);

    if(userUnit[0] == letter[0]){        
        printf("%.6lf lb",poundToGram(conversions));

    }else if(userUnit[0] == letter[1]){
        printf("%.6lf ft",meterToFoot(conversions));

    }else if(userUnit[0] == letter[2]){        
        printf("%.6lf f",fahrToCelc(conversions));
    }

    return 0;    
}

//Function declarations
double fahrToCelc(double cel){
    double fahr = 32 +(1.8*cel);
    return printf("%lf",fahr);
}

double meterToFoot(double meter){
    double foot = meter*0.3048;    
    return printf("%lf", foot);
}

double poundToGram(double gram){
    double pound = gram/0.002205;    
    return printf("%lf",pound);
}
```